# In Blackberry, how are shared objects in runtimestore recognized by other applications

Tags: blackberry

In Blackberry Runtime Store, when sharing objects between applications. How can we call methods of the shared object in another application, if the object itself is not recognized in the other application ? i am getting a runtime error when object gets typecasted, as that object is not defined in the calling applicatoin .

If i typecast it to super interface and have the interface in another application. When i call getClass() on the object returned from the runtimestore. It shows as concrete class instance stored in the RunTimeStore.

How can a share a object in runtimestore and use it across different applications ?

Comment: Reference Question in Blackberry support forums                                                  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Can-RuntimeStore-store-share-some-customed-objects-across/td-p/572280

Answer (score 0):

The referenced question seems to answer what you're asking.

If you're putting `com.foo.bar.MyClass` which implements the `com.foo.bar.MyInterface` in app1, you need to also have it in app2. The package that your class and interface appears to make a difference.

How is your question different?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have answered your own question - you can typecast to an interface that the calling app is aware of.  If you want to cast to a class/interface that's not defined in the calling app though, you're out of luck - it can't be done.

BlackBerry is based on Java ME (formerly J2ME) which has very limited support for runtime reflection - essentially just class names, which you're already seeing when you get the name of the class from the Runtime Store.  Unlike Java SE/EE you can't call methods on classes using the String names of the methods - it would be very handy to have sometimes, but unfortunately not supported.

So to summarize, if you can't include the class definition in your calling app, derive an interface (or superclass) with the methods the calling app wants to call, make the class implement that interface, and include that interface/superclass in both the calling app and the other app.